# JQuery Mobile: Spinbox script file throwing errors

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am having issues implementing a [spinbox](https://github.com/jtsage/jquery-mobile-spinbox) using the provided scripts. I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'widget' of undefined
```

on the `a.mobile.widget` line in the spinbox.js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/spinbox/latest/jqm-spinbox.min.js"></script>
```

I have tried loading the newest script from gitHub, that that one caused a ton of jQuery mobile errors to be thrown. My spinbox:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="spin">Input spinner</label>
    <input type="text" data-role="spinbox" name="OtherTravelersCount" id="OtherTravelersCount" value="60" min="0" max="100"  runat="server"/>                                        
</div>
```

Is there an issue with my code, or does the SpinBox just not work?

**EDIT**

Here are the errors I get when using the [spinbox code](https://github.com/jtsage/jquery-mobile-spinbox/blob/master/js/jqm-spinbox.js) from gitHub

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'widget' of undefined jqm-spinbox.min.js:7
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function spinbox.js:125
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function spinbox.js:125
```

Comment: check compatibility of that widget. It looks like it's not compatible with jQuery 1.9.